# Java - Counting to 100

Tags: java

I am creating a program that takes a user value and counts with it to 100. (if they entered 5 the program would print 5, 10, 15, 20....100)

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter a number to count to 100: ");
   int x = s.nextInt();


    for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x);
      System.out.print(i + " ");
  }
}
```

Heres what I have, but I keep getting an error saying cannot find symbol, variable i.

Could someone please help me adjust the code so it works properly, thanks!

Comment: You should use programs that format your source code automatically. Then you would have seen this bug more clearly.

Comment: Its for a school assignment and they want us to use a basic IDE so we can find out mistakes ourselves and learn how to use everything without the help.

Comment: IMHO, there is no reason to close this question. It is a valid question, even though a very basic one ... (The question is clear, it contains code to reproduce ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `for` loop condition, which Java interprets as the body for your `for` loop, so `i` is out of scope in the next line.

Remove the semicolon, by changing

```
for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x);
```

to

```
for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out my own question:

```
    for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x;)
      System.out.print(i + " ");
  }
}
```

My semi colon was in the wrong spot.

Comment: ... and, while you are new to Java, learn the lesson that using `{...}` blocks even for 1-liner statements in loops makes a big difference.

Comment: There shouldn't be a semicolon before the `)` either.  I'd be surprised if that compiles.  There should be exactly two semicolons: one between the init and condition, and one between the condition and increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x);
      System.out.print(i + " ");
```

should be

```
for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x)
      System.out.print(i + " ");
```

or

```
for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x){
      System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

a semicolon is used to terminate a statement, meaning that when you add it to the end of your for loop, it runs that entire loop first, then it tries your System.out.print.
But since that is after your for loop, and `int i` is defined inside the for loop it cannot find what `i` is.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the semicolon with a bracket.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number to count to 100: ");
int x = s.nextInt();


for(int i=x;i <=100;i +=x){
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```